# Xamarin Forms iOS build fails with Missing image

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio 2019 on Windows.

When I try and compile / debug the iOS project, I get an error reporting that an Asset image is missing. However, the named image is not part of the project - but something must be referencing it somewhere?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(398,3): error : File not found: /Users/gordon/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/660bf49bafcd3b0726d86bbdc8f9f98e66796d37cc48d5b91f8344eb1954729b/Assets.xcassets/icon_load.imageset/icon_load@2x.png
```

In the Asset Catalog, "Icon_Load" has an image called "icon_load@2.png" (plus others), I cannot find any reference to an image called "icon_load@2x.png" in any file within the solution.

I don't work on the image assets, so don't know the history of the files added, etc.

Comment: I would 1) check .csproj files to see if any reference to that file. 2) delete bin & obj folders, to make sure project does a thorough clean rebuild. 3) Delete that image set from catalog, compile and see what happens. Still complain about that file?  4) Have whoever does work on image assets add it back into the project - maybe something is wrong with the asset itself. (I'm not sure exactly how assets work.)

Comment: That was the problem - there was a reference to "icon_load@2x.png" in the .csproj file. However it was "icon_load%402x.png" so my search missed it to start with!

Comment: Had the same problem though the mentioned file from the error message wasn't in the .csproj so I deleted the imageset and created a new one.